# Resources on building Spring MVC Applications using Annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, annotations

The company I recently joined develops all Spring MVC based projects making full use of Annotations and minimal to no use of XML (the project I am currently working on uses only tiles.xml for tiles configuration).

The vast majority of books and tutorials I have come through during the past are focused on XML configurations. In order to get up to speed with the development team I work in a "reverse engineering" style by searching things that I am unfamiliar with in my project.

Clearly this is time-consuming and counter-productive because I have scattered references for various aspects (how to configure a bean in one tutorial, how to configure resolver in another etc.).

Official Spring documentation has proven really useful in many areas, but I would prefer to read a tutorial/series of tutorials/book that is based on Annotations and use the official documentation for reference/cross-check.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this was really useful. 
http://websystique.com/spring-4-mvc-tutorial/

And Configurations of one of my existing projects might help you.

AppInitializer.java instead of web.xml

```
@Configuration
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
}
```

AppConfig.java for config spring mvc

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.aaaa.bbbb")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
}
```

And Hibernate Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.jjjj.kkkk.pojo" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.automaticschema"));
    properties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider",
            environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"));
    properties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase",
            environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase"));

    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}
}
```

Thanks